# Sorting a list of tuples into groups

Tags: sorting, haskell, grouping

I have defined a type:

`type Sortable = [(String, Integer)]`

I would would to sort these into groups based on the string. Right now, I have:

```
funsort :: Sortable -> [Sortable] -> [Sortable]
funsort [] ret = ret
funsort ((name, value):xs) ret =
  let unsorted = (filter ((/=name).fst) xs) in
  let filtered = (filter ((==name).fst) xs) in
  let listofsortedlists = ((name,value) : homies) in
  funsort unsorted (ret : listofsortedlists)
```

It seems to me that this should work, but it doesn't. :-/

I just get:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘(String, Value)’ with ‘[Sortable]’
  Expected type: [[Sortable]]
    Actual type: [(String, Value)]
• In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘sortedlistoflists’
  In the second argument of ‘funsort’, namely ‘(ret : sortedlistoflists)’
  In the expression: funsort unsorted (ret : sortedlistoflists)
```

Comment: What doesn't work and what is expected? Could you provide sample cases?

Comment: sortable should not be list. It should only be tuple.

Comment: I want sortable to have that format. Changing the specification wouldn't achieve what I want. It makes sense in the larger picture.

Comment: I recommend you don't use tail-recursion style unless you have a specific reason. Functions that yield a list are usually better expressed with direct recursion – and they have better performance, too; tail recursion only makes sense with a strict accumulator.

Comment: Not sure you want, Would you give a simple example to describe what the desired result of funsort function?

Comment: It would help if you gave meaningful names to your variables.

Comment: Sure, if I have the list:

`[("a", 1), ("b",1), ("a",2), ("c",0)]`

I want to end up with: `[[("a",1), ("a",2)], [("b",1)], [("c",0)]]`

Comment: See `Data.List.group`.

Comment: use `Data.List.group` only after `sortBy (comparing fst)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just switched the order of arguments to `(:)`:

```
funsort :: Sortable -> [Sortable] -> [Sortable]
funsort [] ret = ret
funsort ((name, value):xs) ret =
  let unsorted = (filter ((/=name).fst) xs) in
  let filtered = (filter ((==name).fst) xs) in
  let listofsortedlists = ((name,value) : filtered) in
  funsort unsorted -- (ret : listofsortedlists)   -- wrong order
                   (listofsortedlists : ret)
```

And it works with `[]` as the initial key-values store, as you no doubt intended:

```
> funsort [("1",1), ("2",10), ("1",100)] []
[[("2",10)],[("1",1),("1",100)]]
it :: [Sortable]
```

Building a result list in reverse by consing unto a list is a common idiom in the more imperative, non-lazy functional languages. In Haskell, thanks to laziness, we can build a list in a top-down manner, with *"guarded"* recursion:

```
funsort [] = []
funsort ((name, value):xs) =
  let unsorted = (filter ((/=name).fst) xs) in
  let filtered = (filter ((==name).fst) xs) in
  let listofsortedlists = ((name,value) : filtered) in
  listofsortedlists : funsort unsorted
```

so that there's no need for the extra argument and the result comes in the right order:

```
> funsort [("1",1), ("2",10), ("1",100)]
[[("1",1),("1",100)],[("2",10)]]
```

A more performant way to code this though, is to go via the `Data.Map.Map String [Int]` route. Leaving it for your researching pleasure.

cf. [`FromList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:fromListWith) and friends.